# Function showing same result count product have left WooCommerce

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I want showing products have left / total product and show by the progress bar, on product page work fine, but on loop page (category, shop page) just showing the same result of one product, this should be a different 
result on a product. Here is the code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  'use strict';
    var wbpsSale = jQuery('#wpbsc_total_sale').attr('total-sale');
    var wbpsStock = jQuery('#wpbsc_total_sale').attr('total-stock');
    var jqmeter_params = {
        goal:wbpsStock,
        raised:wbpsSale,
        meterOrientation:'horizontal',
        displayTotal: true,  
        width:'100%',
        height:'17px'
        };
  jQuery("corergb-bar").jQMeter(jqmeter_params);

});
```

```
    function wpbsc_show_stock_shop() {
        global $product;
        global $post;
        $manage_stock = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_manage_stock', true );
        if( $product->is_on_sale() && $product && $manage_stock == 'yes'){

        $stock = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_stock', true );
        $wpbscSale = $product->get_total_sales();
        $wpbscTotalStock = intval($stock)+ intval($wpbscSale);
        ?>

        <div class="wpbsc-stock-counter">
           <div id="wpbsc_total_sale" class="total-sale-stat" total-sale="<?php echo esc_attr( $wpbscSale ); ?>" total-stock="<?php echo esc_attr($wpbscTotalStock) ?>"></div>
            <p class="stock-progressbar-status"><span class="total-sold"> <?php echo esc_html__("Đã bán: {$wpbscSale}",'wpbsc'); ?></span></p>
            <div id="corergb-bar" class="bar-progress-stat"></div>
        </div>


       <?php
      }
    }
```

Pls help me, i want showing to hook "woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title" with different 
result on a product

image example:

[here is showing on product page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGyM6.jpg)

[showing on category but only progress bar not with percent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LWoB.jpg)

when i change
`jQuery("[id='corergb-bar']")`
to
`jQuery('.bar-progress-stat')`
the result progress bar showing but same result for all product have manage_stock

image example:
[should be different result on a product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K96hO.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**:
A very simple alternative would be to use a progress bar provided by your CSS framework as most of them do include one. For example, if you use bootstrap then you use find the documentation for it's progress bar [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/progress/).

It is very simple:

```
<div class="progress">
<div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: <?php echo ((esc_attr( $wpbscSale )*100)/esc_attr( $wpbscTotalStock )); ?>%" aria-valuenow="<?php echo esc_attr( $wpbscSale ); ?>" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="<?php echo esc_attr($wpbscTotalStock) ?>">
</div>
```

Previous **Incorrect** deduction:
After taking a quick look, I think you might not be getting a value for your `$stock` variable. Could you try to use `$product->get_id()` instead of `$post->ID` at `$stock = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_stock', true );` and then try again?

So it should look like: `$stock = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_stock', true );`

You could also try to use `[get_the_id()][1]` instead. **Edit**: You are supposed to use [get_the_id()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_id/) without the object reference.

Comment: thanks for reply, `$stock` is work fine with `$stock = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_stock', true );` i checked on devtool, but i still try to change like you said and the result showing `NaN%`, don't work.

Comment: My bad, it was meant to be `$product->get_id()` but regardless, if you are able to fetch the same with your code then it should't be a concern.

I think, the issue is with your jQuery code. You are taking in `wbpsSale` and `wbpsStock` on the bases of the ID and since it is a loop, you end up with multiple elements with the same ID on the page which is not how it should be. When your jQuery runs it probably just picks the first element with the mentioned ID and uses it to initialize `jqmeter_params`, this is then used to apply progress bar setting allover the page resulting same bar on all.

Comment: i change to `$stock = get_post_meta( $product->get_the_id(), '_stock', true );`, but showing error `Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method WC_Product_Simple::get_the_id()`.

yes I'm sure you're right about the problem, can you tell me how to fix this

Comment: `You are taking in wbpsSale and wbpsStock on the bases of the ID and since it is a loop, you end up with multiple elements with the same ID on the page which is not how it should be. When your jQuery runs it probably just picks the first element with the mentioned ID and uses it to initialize jqmeter_params, this is then used to apply progress bar setting allover the page resulting same bar on all`
This is exactly the problem I am having

Comment: I'm just one noob trying to help others :) Just check once if my code goes along with your logic. It would currently be showing progress according to `how many have been sold` and NOT `how many are left`. Although one can easily deduce one from the other but still worth a look.